# MPMoviePlayerViewController cannot play url

Tags: ios, objective-c, streaming, remote-access

I am trying to play remote video with MPMoviePlayerViewController like this.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT1211/sample_iTunes.mov"];

self.mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                                  initWithContentURL:url];

[self.navigationController presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.mp];
```

I can play above url. However, I can't play my own video file url like this. It is running on local server and it is pointing to file location.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/through_your_eyes/file0.mov
```

Is it client or server side problem? Shall I point to file location on server side or how shall I prepare?

Comment: Simulator or device?

Answer (score 0):

**It is server side problem**

From your end you are doing well.

When you trying to play video -  getting error like this

```
_itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
    kind = 1;
    new = 2;
    old = 0;
}
```

This shows that `MPMoviePlayerViewController` not able to play video from this `url`.

**Reasons:**

1. **Your url is not proper** - print `NSURL` object check its proper and escape character are there (If required)
2. **Permission** - It is not permitted to play this video from device. Firewall stop access this video from device. Check that you are permitted to access the url
3. **Video format** - Some times video conversion changes the formate of the video. You can see the correct format of the video how ever if conversion is made it is not able to play by the device. Please copy this **url** paste it in Simulator **Safari** app and check it is able to play.

Comment: It is quite strange. I cannot play inside my application. URL is like this. http://192.168.1.8:8000/media/through_your_eyes/file0.mov
I cannot play from Simulator Safari also but I can play from my computer Safari browser.

Comment: As i said - Computer Safari browser has plugin, Or what i can say some inbuilt capabilities to play almost all kind of videos. For device we should take care of this when we dealing with video playing. Video format which is supported by iOS (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH9-SW4)

Comment: Yes. My video type is mov. I think apple support

Comment: How ever your video type is `.mov` it is case that it can't be play (may be some codecs are different). I had a case and i tested a scenario like this - I record video form iMac using QuickTimePlayer, Drag it to simulator safari but not able to play that video (its is `.mov` format). Then from `QuickTimePlayer` file menu export this video for iPhone,iPad supporting format.